# Not able to get rid of user credential request pop up using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-security

I am integrating Spring Security into my Spring MVC and Angular App.

**Versions:**

Spring Security: 4.1.5.RELEASE

Spring MVC: 4.2.0.RELEASE

Angular: 4

After integration, I see that browser is showing pop up for user name and password. Even after following changes, I am not able to get rid of the pop up and proceed further to my custom login form in angular.

---

To start with I am using http basic authentication mechanism.
For this created following **`SecurityConfig.java`**.
**[Updated]**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:on
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("user1").roles("USER").and().withUser("user2")
                .password("user2").roles("USER").and().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        // @formatter:off

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:on
        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/login", "*.*", "/*.bundle.*", "/*.ico")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        // @formatter:off
    }

}
```

For resource and path resolution, created following **`ServletContextConfiguration.java`** .

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ServletContextConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
         configurer.favorPathExtension(true).ignoreAcceptHeader(true).useJaf(false)
         .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).mediaType("html",
         MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
         .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).mediaType("json",
         MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean(name = "contentNegotiatingViewResolver")
    public ViewResolver getContentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/dist/").resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }

}
```

Following is my **`web.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I am using weblogic server to deploy war file.

**`weblogic.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:context-root>/</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>oracle.core.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>oracle.jdbc.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>oracle.net.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>oracle.sql.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>oracle.security.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Angular Changes:

In **`app.module.ts`** introduced http interceptor to inject http header `X-Requested-With` as suggested [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_login_page_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_ii).

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StoreComponent } from './components/store/store.component';
import { StoreService } from './services/store.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './components/logout/logout.component';

@Injectable()
export class XhrInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const xhr = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
    });
    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>HttpRequest intercepted...");
    return next.handle(xhr);
  }
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path:'', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
  { path: 'store', component: StoreComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StoreComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [ StoreService, { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: XhrInterceptor, multi: true } ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

By some reason, still I am able to see the default user name and password pop up from browser.
In web console, I don't see the `X-Requested-With` header. Also, I don't see my console log which should have been printed while http request is intercepted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think, request might not be reaching angular client and something wrong happened in server side.
What could be missing here?

---

**Update:**

As suggested, I have replaced `http.basic()` request with `http.authorizeRequests()`. Now, pop up is not displayed for `/login` request. But after once I try to submit user credentials in my custom login page by calling `/authenticate`, again I see the pop up :(

What could be missing here.

[image]

Please clarify.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you able to fix your problem. I have the same problem. if you can help... Thanks-Sudhir

Answer (score 1):

this is due to `http.httpBasic()` in your config, it should be `http.authorizeRequests()`

Answer (score 1):

You are still using spring security's http basic authentication, that is why is it showing basic authentication pop up, dont use it , use http.autherizeRequest() and using machers permit your login url.
And in routemodule define same path for login component. It will work.

Comment: But in Spring Security tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_login_page_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_ii , I don't understand why he spoke about http.basic() and to avoid() pop up introduction of X-Requested-With header in client side, which is not making any difference here.

Comment: May be x-request with header also works, but i also faced the same issue while following this official document. I followed other documentation for custom login form in spring security with angular and that worked.